# Angular Material 2 Can't Suppress Required Asterisk

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material, angular-material2

I'm struggling to suppress the asterisk on placeholder for required input and select fields in an angular material 2 form. Here is the html:

```
  <form class="project-info-container">
    <h3 color="primary">Inputs</h3>
    <md-input-container>
      <input md-input placeholder="Contact Email" [(ngModel)] = "contact.email" name="email" md-no-asterisk required>
    </md-input-container><br />
    <md-input-container>
      <input md-input placeholder="Permit Number" [(ngModel)] = "project.permitNumber" name="number" md-no-asterisk required>
    </md-input-container><br />
    <md-input-container>
      <input md-input placeholder="Project Name" [(ngModel)] = "project.projectName" name="name" md-no-asterisk required>
    </md-input-container><br />
    <md-input-container>
      <input md-input placeholder="Project Address" [(ngModel)] = "project.address" name="address" md-no-asterisk required >
    </md-input-container><br />
    <md-select [(ngModel)] = "submissionNumber" name = "subnum" class = "submission-select" color="primary" placeholder="Submission Number" md-no-asterisk required>
      <md-option *ngFor = "let sub of subs" [value] = "sub">
        {{sub}}
      </md-option>
    </md-select>
  </form>
```

As you can see, I'm attempting to use the `md-no-asterisk` attribute, to no avail. Also, I've deleted the `::after` style on the placeholder class in the following stylesheets:

```
/node_modules/@angular/material/input/input.css
/node_modules/@angular/material/input/input.scss
/node_modules/@angular/material/select/select.css
/node_modules/@angular/material/select/select.scss
```

The form still renders with the asterisks and I'm stumped as to why. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As you can check in this Pr : https://github.com/angular/material2/pull/4237/files/c395b2019459f1e24494dcdcce21e6aa8e4bd899#diff-57ec6b8f9c25230070b7d749bc04c51b

There is an element call hideRequiredMarker that you could use for your case

```
<md-input-container [hideRequiredMarker]="true">
```

It have been push less than a month ago on master so you need quite a recent version of angular & material